# Canceling nested Promise gives warning: "pending promise deallocated"

Tags: swift, promisekit

I have the following code snippet which gives me the warning: "pending promise deallocated", when canceling the underlying task.

```
func pingGoogle() -> Promise<Void> {
    Promise { seal in
        firstly {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
        }.done { _ in
            seal.fulfill_()
        }.catch {
            seal.reject($0)
        }
    }
}

pingGoogle()
URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { tasks in tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } }
```

I am not entirely sure why this is happening, nor how to solve it.
Could someone with more experience point me in the right direction?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. Because the task is canceled and `.catch` does not catch cancelation errors by default, my Promise was being deallocated without ever getting rejected.

This fixed it:

```
.catch(policy: .allErrors) {
    seal.reject($0)
}
```

I'll leave this here for future reference, should anyone have a similar problem!